# Using boost::bind with a class containing a boost::mutex

Tags: c++, boost-thread, boost-bind, boost-mutex

I'm working on a server using a watchdir to add items to an internal collection. The watchdir is browsed periodically by a thread which is created like this :

```
this->watchDirThread = new boost::thread(boost::bind(&Filesystem::watchDirThreadLoop,
                                                      this,
                                                      this->watchDir,
                                                      fileFoundCallback));
```

The `fileFoundCallback` parameter is also created via `boost::bind` :

```
boost::bind(&Collection::addFile, this->collection, _1)
```

I would like to protect my collection from concurrent access using a mutex but my problem is that the `boost::mutex` class is non copyable, therefore there can't be a mutex in my `Collection` class since `boost::bind` requires copyable parameters.

I don't like the idea of a static mutex because it would be semantically wrong as the role of the mutex here is to prevent my collection to be read while it's being modified.

What can I do to solve this problem ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [std::ref or std::cref](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/ref) around the mutex. That is, instead of:

```
boost::mutex yourmutex;
boost::bind(..., yourmutex, ...);
```

write:

```
boost::mutex yourmutex;
boost::bind(..., std::ref(yourmutex), ...);
```